# How to use latest cometd version in Salesforce StreamingAPI

Tags: streaming-api, cometd

Following the instructions [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Streaming_Real_Time_Data_into_Visualforce) I was able to set up StreamingAPI in my org with cometd version 2.2.0.

Salesforce are now advising that we upgrade to at least 3.0.9 so I've downloaded the latest version - 3.1.2 and am trying to follow the same process to create my static resource.  Files are not all located in the same places as in the 2.2.0 zip file however I extracted cometd.js from the war file, found cometd-jquery.js and json2.js and created a static resource of the three.

The code in my visualforce page hasn't changed but I'm now getting the following error message in the console:

GET 
https://cs9.salesforce.com/cometd/39.0/ [HTTP/1.1 405 Only POST is allowed 254ms]

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://cs9.salesforce.com/cometd/39.0/.  cometd.js:891:85

Has anyone used recent versions of cometd in Salesforce?  If so, how did you go about setting it up?  What is different to the instructions salesforce provide for version 2.2.0?

Thanks

Comment: Any luck? I'm wondering the same. Perhaps this helps https://github.com/developerforce/SalesforceDurableStreamingDemo/commit/8d393cb82242fb87c9a6131bc63432b790926adc where they update the demo to use 3.1.0.

Comment: I have built a static resource with the files from that example and the notifications do seem to work, however I get a console warning:  "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at wss://cs9.salesforce.com/cometd/39.0/." which concerns me even though the notifications are arriving.  I have a case open with Salesforce at the moment, I'll update it and see what they come back with.

Comment: Great, looking forward to your findings. I'm using the old version and have been, but I noticed that it stops receiving updates after a while, so I was hoping the new version would help, but it sounds like maybe not quite... yet.

Comment: any luck?  Was hoping I could just NPM install cometd into my project but I'm getting the same error.  NPM doesn't even go back as far as the version salesforce is using

Comment: @ministe2003 that message you receive is expected. It's cometd attempting to open a websocket connection and failing.  When this happens it falls back to the long-polling Transport. If you add `cometd.websocketEnabled = false;`, it won't attempt to connect.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you were setting up the connection cross domain. It appears the [streaming API isn't supported](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/extend_code_cors.htm).

Since salesforce hasn't setup CORS, the Preflight request will fail and you'll see that `cometd` is defaulting back to the [Callback Polling Transport](https://github.com/cometd/cometd-documentation/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/javascript_transports.adoc#the-callback-polling-transport), which is then rejected because the endpoint only allows POST.

I've tried the exact same code in a VF page and it works, but it fails when it's cross domain.

Here's what the code looks like using the 3.1.3

```
const lib = require('cometd');
const cometd = new lib.CometD();

// Configure the CometD object.
cometd.configure({
    url: `${yoursalesforceinstance}/cometd/42.0/`,
    requestHeaders: { Authorization: `OAuth ${yoursalesforcetoken}`},
    appendMessageTypeToURL: false,
});

// Handshake with the server.
cometd.handshake(function(h) {
  if (h.successful) {
        // Subscribe to receive messages from the server.
        cometd.subscribe('/topic/MyTopic', function(m) {
            const dataFromServer = m.data;
            console.log(dataFromServer);
        });
    }
});
```

If you really need it to work cross-domain, you could [pass it through a proxy](https://github.com/jamesward/sf-cors-proxy).